# How do I create a directory in all subdirectories?

Tags: bash, directory, wildcards

Suppose I have a directory structure like this:

```
$ [~/practice] ls
a/ b/ c/ d/
```

Now I want to create a directory `tmp1` in all sub directories of `practice` and I do this:

```
$ [~/practice] mkdir */tmp1
mkdir: cannot create directory `*/tmp1': No such file or directory
```

Then I try the `-p` switch and I endup with a directory named `*` with a sub directory `tmp1`

```
$ [~/practice] mkdir -p */tmp1

$ [~/practice] ls
*/ a/ b/ c/ d/
```

I know the use of `-p` switch is to create multiple nonexistent directories. I just thought it might help.

How do I create `tmp1` in all subdirectories at once?

If this can be done, how do I extend it to create `\tmp1`, `\tmp2`, `\tmp3` in `\a`, `\b` and `\c` at once?

**Edit:** I missed mentioning that the directories don't have to be simple and in order, like `a`, `b`, `c` etc., and the directory to be created is not necessarily like `tmp1`, `tmp2`.

```
$ [~/practice] ls
dog/ cat/ rat/
```

In them, I would like to have something like

```
$ [~/practice] ls *
dog:
red/ blue/

cat:
red/ blue/

rat:
red/ blue/
```

Comment: Given [Christopher's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/61913), you should clarify whether "create \tmp1, \tmp2, \tmp3 in \a, \b and \c" should result a total of 3 or 9 subdirectories.

Comment: @manatwork: That's a good point. It should create 9 subdirectories.

Comment: This my help to solve the space issue in the name of the directory
sudo find ./ -depth -type d -exec echo '"{}/RCS"' \;

Answer (score 61, accepted):

With [globs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) :

```
for dir in */; do mkdir -- "$dir/tmp1"; done
```

### NOTE

- I treat only dirs (including symlinks to dirs) with the little hack of using `*/` as a glob
- If you want to create multiple subdirs at once :

  `for dir in */; do mkdir -- "$dir"/{tmp1,foo,bar,qux}; done`

Comment: Could I do `for i in */; do mkdir "$i/itemone" "$i/itemtwo"; done` for multiple, not-in-order directory names?

Comment: I tested this and it is very much possible. Thanks.

Comment: See my edited post

Comment: Brace expansion is not performed in quoted string.

Comment: Yes, thanks, post edited by Stephane Chazelas accordingly...

Comment: what purpose does the -- serve here?

Comment: Necessary to pass files beginning with `-` (means _end of parameters_)

Comment: i was lookin to also rename dir recursively & the above cmnd worked like charm `for dir in */; do mv "$dir/foo" "$dir/bar"; done ` thanx again

Comment: What do the `--` dashes do in the `do` clause?

Comment: @DrKumar: it means _end of parameters_

Comment: Necessary if the filename in the variable start with `-`

Answer (score 11):

> [...] how do I extend it to create \tmp1, \tmp2, \tmp3 in \a, \b and \c at once?

```
 mkdir {a,b,c}/tmp{1,2,3}
```

Answer (score 10):

With GNU or BSD* find:

```
find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec mkdir {}/newdir \;
```

or using parameter expansion:

```
dirs=(*/)
mkdir -- "${dirs[@]/%/newdir}"
```

*Includes OS X

Comment: With standard find syntax: `find . -name . -o -prune -type d -exec sh -c 'exec mkdir "$1/newdir"' sh {} \;`

Comment: Also note the differences between the two solutions: the first one includes hidden directories, the second one will add a newdir in the directories linked by any symlink in the current directory.

Answer (score 6):

Off topic since you're mentioning `bash`, but for the record, with zsh, you'd do:

```
dirs=(*(/))
mkdir -- $^dirs/tmp1
```

`$^var` turns on *brace-like* expansion for the expansion of the array. It's reminiscent of `rc`'s `^` operator and in `rc` (or its derivative `es`), you'd write it:

```
dirs=(*/)
mkdir -- $dirs^tmp1
```

However note (and the same applies to the bash solutions given here) that in the rc solution `dirs` would also contain symbolic links to directories. In the zsh solution, change `*(/)` to `*(-/)` if you want to include symlinks to directories.

Comment: +1 for your point about symlinks! This behavior may be desired, but mkdir's complaint about creating a duplicate directory can be suppressed with the `-p` flag.

Answer (score 5):

Portably, loop over the parent directories:

```
for d in */; do mkdir "$d/red" "$d/blue"; done
```

Add `--` after `mkdir` if you may have directories whose name starts with `-`.

In zsh, you can do it in a single command with the `e` [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers):

```
mkdir *(/e\''REPLY=($REPLY/{red,blue})'\')
```

but it's quicker to type this as two commands:

```
d=(*(/)); mkdir $^d/{red,blue}
```

Comment: On a site that is meant to be a reference, I'd rather say "`mkdir -- whatever`, and _omit_ `--` if you intend for the expansion of _whatever_ to be possibly taken as options to the `mkdir` command.". There's no point in omiting `--` here. It may not be a problem in the OP's case, but it is one in the general case. I think we have a duty to teach the correct and safe syntax here.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas In a scripting context, I always put all necessary `--` and quotes and big fat warnings when newlines aren't supported. In a command line context, I prefer to show the quick version that works in practice first, and the bulletproof version as a complement.

Answer (score 1):

Variation on sputnick's answer which avoids non-directory files:

```
for x in *; do if [ -d "$x" ]; then mkdir "$x/tmp1"; fi; done
```

Comment: I treat only dirs, that"s all the magic...

Comment: cool, got it ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that like that:

```
mkdir {a,b,c,d}/tmp1
```

Comment: What if he has 100 directories?

Answer (score 1):

This is a good one from the old Unix Masters (tested on FreeBSD 10.1) if you want to version control (with RCS check in locked: ci -l with a brief comment as ir: for initial release) your /etc/* config files on ~/.his/etc

```
sudo rsync -av /etc/ ~/.his
sudo find -d ~/.his/etc -type d -exec echo '{}/RCS' \; | xargs sudo mkdir -p
sudo find -d ~/.his/etc \! -name "RCS" | xargs sudo ci -l -mir -t-ir
```

Comment: I fail to see how this answer the OP

Answer (score 1):

Should be \! name "RCS" and it works best on the first check in.

sudo find ~/.his/etc \! -name "RCS" -ls

sudo find -d ~/.his/etc \! -name "RCS" | xargs sudo ci -l -mir -t-ir

This last one also works very well for the cjeck in part filtering all RCS content on the file name:

sudo find -d ~/.his/etc -type f | grep -v RCS | xargs sudo ci -l -mir -t-ir

Answer (score 1):

this is a great help to me. i had a need to create a set of subdirectories in multiple folders and something like:

```bsh
!/bin/sh

cd /dest/cont

for dir in */*/; do
    mkdir -p -- $dir/{FB,Video,Audio,proj};
done
```

worked great except when a white space is encountered. is there a way to ignore spaces in the `*/*/` part of the arguments?